# LaunchServices: Failed to create bundleProxy for bundle...?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem, launch-services

What does this LaunchServices error message (from Console.app) mean?

```
2015-12-13 4:57:48.365 PM bird[344]: LaunchServices: Failed to create bundleProxy for bundle com.mowglii.ItsycalApp
```

***Background***: I wrote a small calendar app that lives in the menu bar. When a user clicks its NSStatusItem icon, a calendar is displayed below it. The app gives the user the option of automatically launching at login. One of my users who has this option turned on gets the above error message logged. The app seems to launch at login (the NSStatusItem is visible in the menu bar), but when the user clicks on the NSStatusItem, nothing happens. The user then double-clicks the app's icon in his Applications folder and then is able to click on the NSStatusItem to pull down the calendar. He is running OS X 10.11.1. The app is not sandboxed.

The issue I'm trying to solve is the app's unresponsiveness when it automatically launches at login on this user's machine. I am only guessing that the error message above is related. I don't get that message when I run the app on my 10.11 machine and I don't get the unresponsive behavior at login.

Since I can't reproduce the behavior or the log message, I'm stumped. Can anyone help?